# Need help using a variable to define -Properties for Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script for getting all the members of various AD Groups but recently we have been needed to get more then just the names of the members and need to get various properties such as Title or Office. I tried adjusting my script so that you could input what properties you needed to define but it isn't working as I would like so I was hoping someone might be able to help.

Here is my original script:

```
$EndDate = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")
$FileName = $ADGroup + '_' + $EndDate + '_ADGroupReport.csv'
$FilePath = 'P:\Information Technology\IT Reports\' + $FileName

function Get-Members {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Enter a valid AD Group.")]
        [string]$ADGroup,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, HelpMessage="Enter valid AD Properties seperated by a comma.")]
        $Properties
    )


    process {
        if (!$Properties) {
            Get-ADGroupmember -identity $ADGroup | select name | Export-Csv -Path $FilePath
            
        } else {
            Get-ADGroupmember -identity $ADGroup | where{$_.ObjectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser -Properties '$Properties' | select name, $Properties | Export-Csv -Path $FilePath
        }
    }
}

$Group = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter a valid AD Group:'
$Prop = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter any additional properties needed:'

Get-Members -ADGroup $Group -Properties $Prop
```

This appears to work in the try phase if I only enter 1 property, but then fails on the finally stage. If I enter multiple properties, such as title,office then it fails at both stages.

The error I get when entering additional properties is below. My assumption is that it doesn't like this as a string and would prefer an array? I am not sure honestly on how to handle this.

```
Get-ADUser : One or more properties are invalid.
Parameter name: $Properties
At line:10 char:79
+ ... bjectClass -eq "user"} | Get-ADUser -Properties '$Properties' | selec ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (REDACTED) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Before anyone says anything, I am aware the try block will fail if no properties are entered, its only in there for my testing currently.

Comment: How are the different properties separated in `$Prop = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter any additional properties needed:'` ?? You should make that clear to the user entering the data. Then in your function, split the given string in `$Properties` by that delimiter character. (remember someone can enter just about **anything** in Read-Host, so you need to build in checks to see if the input is workable at all.)

Comment: In my testing I am separating them with a comma, which I figured should just work since if I hard code the properties they are separated by a comma and work just fine.  I'll make sure to add it to the prompt on how they should be separated.

Comment: Then all you need is to split on the comma I guess  `-Properties ($Properties -split ',')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see three issues on your code, first one, single quotes on `-Properties '$Properties'` will not allow the expansion of the variable `$Properties`, *it would be as passing the literal string.*

Should be:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties $Properties
```

Second issue, doing this `Select-Object Name, $Properties` will throw the following exception (assuming `$Properties` would have been an `array`):

```
$properties = 'email', 'title'

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'User'
    Email = 'user@domain.com'
    Title = 'Administrator'
} | Select-Object Name, $properties
```

> Cannot convert `System.Object[]` to one of the following types {`System.String`, `System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock`}.

You could do something like this so that `Name` is always included in the `$Properties` variable:

```
$properties = ,'name'           # => This is hardcoded
$properties += 'email', 'title' # => This is user input

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = 'User'
    Email = 'user@domain.com'
    Title = 'Administrator'
} | Select-Object $properties

Name Email           Title
---- -----           -----
User user@domain.com Administrator
```

Third issue is the one pointed out by [Theo on his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263756/need-help-using-a-variable-to-define-properties-for-get-aduser#comment124206934_70263756), `Read-Host` will store the user input as `string`, so, *assuming the user is actually using `,` as delimiter of each property*, you can convert the input to an `array` using `-split` or `.split()`:

```
$prop = ,'name'
$prop += (
    Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter any additional properties needed'
).Split(',').ForEach('Trim')
```

Supposing the input was for example `email, title`:

```
Enter any additional properties needed: email, title
name
email
title
```

Comment: I actually just made all those changes and was about to comment what was the resolution but I didn't do the trim after the split for the array, I will add that!

Comment: @Caleb the AD Module might be clever enough to ignore leading and trailing spaces on each element of the array, but just to be sure I think it was worth adding it hehe